# Why don't people want to pay/donate for my software?

Tags: license, source-code, donations

Apologies if this is no the correct forum for my question - it looked like good fit though!

I have some software ( [www.rgraph.net](http://www.rgraph.net) ) that I used to sell - thus it was commercial. This was OK for a few years but it kept dropping further and further in Gooogle rank such that no one would find it and subsequently use or pay for it. So it's now Open Source (MIT license). I've been developing it constantly over the past 15 years and as a result, it's now a very capable library.

I recently found the issue with Google hating the site (in March 2023) and have risen in rank - but I'm hoping for more rises in the future.

My question is: Is my sites traffic still too low (500-600 genuine page views on a good day) to expect any monetary donations (in place of license purchases) - do I need way more traffic?

Comment: It is not very common to donate for Open Source software. The JavaScript ecosystem is comparatively good at this with tools like `npm fund`, but of course this is still going to be a long-tail distribution with most people getting nothing. You still have to give people a reason to pay, e.g. enterprise support, feature development, showing the logo of gold-tier sponsors, and so on. It could also be useful to take a peek at "competitors" like D3, Plotly, or Highcharts. What are their features, how do they present themselves as an awesome tool, and what is their funnel to convert users to cash?

Comment: My model is WinSCP which is GPL and gets quite a lot of donors if their page is to be believed: https://winscp.net/eng/donate.php I get the impression that Highcharts sells a lot of commercial licenses - don't know about the other two. I've always felt that if I could get a good Google rank for the search "javascript charts" I'd get much more traffic and maybe more donations. Feature-wise - RGraph is quite comprehensive IMHO!

Comment: Maybe I should change the license (again) to GPL

Comment: And maybe offer a £99 commercial option alongside it.

Comment: Note how your WinSCP example is giving people a reason to pay: acknowledgements, links, beta access, and more weight in feature prioritization. If your users' only motivation would be licensing, why don't they take roughly the same amount of money and throw it at Highcharts, which is more polished, has more integrations, and has better docs? In any case, it is really really difficult to make money from developer tooling: even if a dev wanted to pay, the hobbyists have no money and the employed ones don't control their own budget.

Comment: I searched for "graphing library javascript" and this page appears on Google's first page results. DuckDuckGo gives a very similar result. Appearing on the first page is not "hating". It just means you are up against a lot of competitors that solve the same problem.

Comment: As a programmer I find the name slightly confusing, since names like RBlahBlahBlah often are popular for things used for the R programming language. If your library was for R, then the name would make more sense. Maybe a few programmers mentally "comment out" your library because they assume it's intended for R programmers.

Comment: You could add a donation button or link to donations page to the main page. That donations are desired is only visible on the 'support' page (and yes, use the word "Donation" or "Donate").